# How do I avoid GPG-signing others' commits?

Tags: security, git, gnupg

I've set a global Git config `commit.gpgsign = true` to automatically sign commits that I make. However, when I rebase or cherry-pick commits, it seems to sign all of them, even if I'm not the author.

How can I tell Git to sign only commits which I authored, automatically? (I realize I could handle each commit manually, but I'd rather not perform a special action for each commit I do or don't want to sign.)

Comment: IMHO, since rebasing or cherry-picking tend to alter the actual _changes_ a commit did (e.g. apply the same diff on different code), it makes a bit of sense that you _would_ also be considered partially responsible for those changes...

Comment: That's an interesting point. I guess it depends upon the workflow and mutual understandings of trust that everyone using a repo have. From a simplistic perspective, it seems like I wouldn't really want to be responsible for others' commits in most cases. I might want to be seen as responsible for *having moved/rebased* the commits, but there isn't really a way of indicating that except perhaps in the commit message.

Comment: The GPG support in git is less about proving who authored a commit and more about determining who let certain code into the (trusted) repository.